# Jmeter - Regex issue with embedded variable and $

Tags: regex, perl, variables, jmeter

Greetings,

In Jmeter's regex component, I am running into an issue when the expression has both a variable AND a literal '*$*'.  It always returns as fail. When I replace the variable with a hardcoded value, it works fine.  I have verified the variable is returning the expected value in previous call.

**Failed Expression:** (variable and literal '$')

```
<option value="${variable}".+?>\$(.+?)</option>
```

**Working Version:** (no variable)

```
<option value="1".+?>\$(.+?)</option>
```

Alternately, if I remove the literal '*$*', it works.

**Alt. Working Expression:** (variable, no literal '$')

```
<option value="${variable}".+?>(.+?)</option>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `[$]` as an alternative to escaping it with a backslash.

Answer (score 3):

Work around has been to replace \$ with \W or \S

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a BeanShell function, which has access to the "vars" object.

For example, vars.get("variable") is equivalent to ${variable}.

[Link 1](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html) <-- Search for Bean on the page

Comment: Thanks for the idea - unfortunatley, I'm running into the same problem.  I understand the syntax to be: 

<option value="${__BeanShell(vars.get("variable"))}".+?>\$(.+?)</option>

To call the function, it leads with '${' which seems to be troublesome.

Source:
http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell