# Jmeter nested regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

Is it possible in Jmeter to make nested regular expression?
Or to execute regex on some ${varible}?
And how - if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using javascript function. In plain javascript you would use `regexp.exec`, here is the example link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

So using the example from the link above, let's store the `cdbBdbsbz` in the variable named `initialvariable` (either by defining `initialvariable` in user defined variables, extracted from some sampler or however) and then do some regex on this variable this regex -> `/d(b+)(d)/ig` meaning (from the example link) :

```
// Match one d followed by one or more b's followed by one d
// Remember matched b's and the following d
// Ignore case
```

So you can do this in the beanshell sampler by adding :

```
vars.put("testregex", "${__javaScript(/d(b+)(d)/ig.exec('${initialVariable}')[1],)}");
```

This is less readable version, you could do it trough java code as well (embedded in the beanshell sampler).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to be sensitive to special characters within the regex, like '$'.

Please see this post: [Jmeter - Regex issue with embedded variable and $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807789/jmeter-regex-issue-with-embedded-variable-and)

And this link for reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dummy Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/DummySampler) for such needs.